# LLVM insert pass into PassManager

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-c++-api

I'm writing a module level pass and inside the `runOnModule` function I have the following bit of code:

```
for (Module::iterator F = M.begin(), FEND = M.end(); F != FEND; ++F){
if (!(*F).isDeclaration()){
  LoopInfo* LI = new LoopInfo();
  LI->runOnFunction(*F);
  lis.push_back(LI);
  for(LoopInfo::iterator L = LI->begin(), LEND = LI->end(); L != LEND; ++L){
    // add all functions
    loops.push_back(*L);
  }
}
```

}

This all compiles but when I run it I get the following error:

```
opt: /include/llvm/PassAnalysisSupport.h:200: AnalysisType 
&llvm::Pass::getAnalysis() const [AnalysisType = llvm::DominatorTreeWrapperPass]:
Assertion `Resolver && "Pass has not been inserted into a PassManager object!"' failed.
```

I tried putting the below code in ``lib/Transforms/IPO/PassManagerBuilder.cpp`in the`populateModulePassManager` method but nothing happened.

```
if (EnableMergeFunctions) {
MPM.add(createMergeFunctionsPass());
MPM.add(createJumpThreadingPass()); // Merge consecutive conditionals
MPM.add(createInstructionCombiningPass());
MPM.add(createCFGSimplificationPass());
```

}

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Did you use addRequired<LoopInfo>() in getAnalysisUsage() ?

Comment: Then if you want to use loop info for a particular function you should use LI=&getAnalysis<LoopInfo>(F)

Comment: I specifically want to use it in the way I've written since I want to store the pointers to all Loops - if I use the `getAnalysis()` API the pointers are invalidated after the `LoopInfo` object goes out of scope.

Comment: You are not using the API the way it is design to do it, if you want help to workaround please update your question with the context of what you try to achieve. Right now it is misleading.